# JQuery DatePicker Link to Month

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have 2 pages. On page 1 I have links and on page 2 I have a JQuery DatePicker.

What I need to do is to have links to the different months.

For example, on page 1 have a link that links to May and when I click on the link it goes to page 2 and the JQuery DatePicker with show May month.

Can this be done please?

UPDATE: Using firebug I've hovered over the datapicker next button and the code is this:

```
onclick="DP_jQuery_1304716221986.datepicker._adjustDate('#dp1304716221987', +1, 'M');"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you have:

```
page1.htm
    <a href="page2.htm?month=4"> April </a>
    <a href="page2.htm?month=5"> May </a>
    <a href="page2.htm?month=6"> June </a>
```

(note that we're appending an url parameter with the number of the month)

In page 2, do this:

```
page2.htm
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   var month = getURLParameter('month') - 1; //-1 cause javascript months start in 0
   var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
   var defaultDate = new Date(currentYear, month, 1); //Set to first day of the month
   $( "#your_datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
      defaultDate: defaultDate 
   });
});
```

As you see, in page2 we read the url param 'month' and create the datepicker with it.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I've tried you code but I'm probably missing something. Using firebug I've hovered over the datapicker next button and the code is this:

onclick="DP_jQuery_1304716221986.datepicker._adjustDate('#dp1304716221987', +1, 'M');" Would this help?

Comment: No, there must be another problem. What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to set the date: .datepicker( "setDate" , date )

And as far as actually showing the datepicker, you might be able to trigger a click event on it or perhaps use the dialog method to show it.

Have a look at the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-dialog

Comment: I also tried:   $("#date").datepicker( "setDate" , defaultDate ); but no changes.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not enough rep yet to simply add a comment. Edgar's sample works, but I'd make one minor change. I'd also pass in the year since you may need it. Depending on how you are implementing this system, I'd imagine you may run into problems requiring a year parameter. So you link would look like this:

```
/page.html?month=1&year=2010
```

And then the js would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var month = getURLParameter('month') - 1; //-1 cause javascript months start in 0
   var currentYear = getURLParameter('year');
   var defaultDate = new Date(currentYear, month, 1); //Set to first day of the month
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({ defaultDate: defaultDate });
});
```

Just be sure to change "#datepicker" to the proper selector.

Comment: There must be some js error on your page then. Try removing anything else you have on that page, or better yet, pull out the date picker stuff and put it into it's own page. Edgar's code works.